# Cannot create LineString on the fly with openlayers and angular

Tags: angular, line, openlayers

I use openlayers 5 and angular6. I get some features of a vector layer, push them in an array ad with that, I try to create a LineString on the fly.

This is my code so far

```
import * as Extent from 'ol/extent.js'; 
import Geometry from 'ol/geom/Geometry.js';
import LineString from 'ol/geom/LineString.js';

 extent: Extent; 
 linestring: LineString; 
 geometry: Geometry;
```

and then the function

```
let features = this.vectorsource.getFeatures(); 
    let pointsline=[];
    features.forEach((item) => {
      if ( item.values_.clicked ){
        var aa = item.getGeometry().getExtent();
        var oo = Extent.getCenter(aa);
        pointsline.push('['+oo+']');        
      } 
    }); 
    if (pointsline.length > 1) {      
      this.linestring = new LineString({coordinates:pointsline}); 
      this.clicledRouteFeature = new Feature({        
        Geometry: this.linestring
      });
      this.clicledRouteFeature.setStyle(new Style({ 
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: 'red',
          width: 22
        })
      })); 
      this.vectorsource.addFeatures(this.clicledRouteFeature);                       
    }
```

This is the bast I can do. Please help me make this work. I get the error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

referring to this line:

```
this.linestring = new LineString({coordinates:pointsline});
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: from API, new LineString(coordinates, opt_layout): 
coordinates is typed Array.<module:ol/coordinate~Coordinate> | Array.<number> , and seems you are passing object, not array

Comment: @ABOS The console says `["[4272579.09,2445014.01]", "[2249964.79300409,4571457.41961698]"]`

Comment: @ABOS I changed my code to `pointsline.push([oo]);`, so now I get `[Array(1), Array(1)]`, each array contains coords like `[4272579.09, 2445014.01]` but the issue remains. Thanks

Comment: not familiar with openlayers, just curious why coordinates are wrapped in string?

Comment: It should be `pointsline.push(oo);`   pointsline needs to be an array of Array(2) not an array of Array(1) containing an Array(2) e.g. `[[4272579.09, 2445014.01], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]]`

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple fix. Change the following line

```
pointsline.push('['+oo+']');
```

to

```
pointsline.push([oo]);
```

Comment: I did that , but the same issue, with the same error remains. It must be something else.

Comment: `this.linestring = new LineString([[123]]);` - just check with this if you are getting the same error ?

Comment: No, but I see no line. I also tried this syntax `this.clicledRouteFeature = new Feature();
      this.clicledRouteFeature.setStyle(new Style({
        stroke: new Stroke({
          color: 'red',
          width: 22
        })
      }));
      this.clicledRouteFeature.setGeometry(new LineString(pointsline));
      this.vectorsource.addFeatures(this.clicledRouteFeature);` (copy/paste somewhere else to make it readable) With this new syntax I get no errors, but I see no line. Thanks

Comment: There are ome syntax errors.  In the original it should be
`this.linestring = new LineString(pointsline);` (pointsline is a parameter, not an option) and 
`this.clicledRouteFeature = new Feature({        
        geometry: this.linestring
      });` (geometry option name is lower case)
 In the comment above either use either `this.vectorsource.addFeature(this.clicledRouteFeature);` (single for single) or `this.vectorsource.addFeatures([this.clicledRouteFeature]);` (plural for array)

Comment: @Mike Thanks. I am a little closer now. But the feature has `extent_: (4) [Infinity, Infinity, -Infinity, -Infinity]` that is wrong. But all the points that I click to create the linestring's points are normal points that I can see on my map. How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: oo is a center which should already be a coordinate pair array [x,y] in which case try pointsline.push(oo); instead of pointsline.push([oo]);

Comment: @Mike Ah, thanks. This solved it. Thanks for your time and effort in this question and the previous one. You really helped me. Feel free to gather up all your comment to a single answer, so I can upvote properly. Thank you